# Why doesn't biobliography with achemso.bst contain article titles

Tags: bibtex, natbib, achemso

First: I know this question has already been discussed, but the answers don't apply to my case. I want to submit an article to the ACS Journal of Physical Chemistry C using the achemso document class. Recently, this Journal has changed its guidelines for the reference formatting, and titles now HAVE to be encluded. The new configuration file jpccck.cfg (achemso version 3.8d as of 2013/10/04) seems to account for this change by setting

```
articletitle = true
```

but this has no effect on the formatting of the References section in my case. The following minimal example illustrates this problem:

```
\documentclass[
journal=jpccck,
manuscript=article
]{achemso}

\title{foo}
\date{\today}

\author{Test Person}
\email{tp@uni.com}
\affiliation{00000 Bar Germany}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\cite{testentry}

\bibliography{literature}

\end{document}
```

The content of literature.bib looks like this:

```
@article{testentry,
title = {Test Title of Importance},
volume = {108},
number = {3},
journal = {Proc. Nation. Ac. Sci.},
author = {Testperson Two and Testperson Three},
year = {2013},
pages = {972--984},
}
```

Compiling with PDFLaTex, this gives me the following entry in the References section:

```
    (1) Two, T.; Three, T. Proc. Nation. Ac. Sci. 2013, 108, 972–984.
```

Maybe I should add that when updating the achemso package to version 3.8d, the achemso.bst file was updated as well, so the problem cannot come from an older version of it.

EDIT: This is the file list in the output of \listfiles:

```
 achemso.cls    2013/10/04 v3.8d Submission to ACS journals
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
 size12.clo     2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
 geometry.sty   2008/12/21 v4.2 Page Geometry
 ifpdf.sty      2009/04/10 v2.0 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifvtex.sty     2008/11/04 v1.4 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 geometry.cfg
 caption.sty    2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
 caption3.sty   2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
 float.sty      2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
 graphicx.sty   1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 graphics.sty   2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 trig.sty       1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
 graphics.cfg   2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
 pdftex.def     2010/03/12 v0.04p Graphics/color for pdfTeX
 setspace.sty   2000/12/01 6.7 Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package
 url.sty        2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 jpccck.cfg     2013/10/04 v3.8d achemso configuration: J. Phys. Chem. C
 natbib.sty     2009/11/07 8.31a (PWD, AO)
 natmove.sty    2010/01/15 v1.1a Automatic citation moving with natbib
 mciteplus.sty  2008/09/30 v1.1 enhanced mcite
```

Comment: Could you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the resulting `File list` into the question? For me, this all works fine: I wonder what version of the config file you are using.

Comment: OK, did you try deleting all of the auto-generated files and re-running LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still got the same problem.

Comment: OK, I'm suspicious of the version of `achemso.bst` in use. What do `kpsewhich achemso.cls` and `kpsewhich achemso.bst` report from the Command Line/Terminal? Also, what is in the 'control' `.bib` file: you should have `ctrl-article-title  = "yes",` amongst other things.

Comment: The content of the acs-control file is as expected:

Comment: accidentally hit enter... @Control{achemso-control,
  ctrl-article-title  = "yes",
  ctrl-chapter-title  = "no",
  ctrl-etal-number    = "8",
  ctrl-etal-firstonly = "no",
}

Comment: achemso.cls is located in ~/texmf/tex/latex/achemso3.8d/achemso.cls, but achemso.bst is taken from /usr/share/texmf-texlive/bibtex/bst/achemso/achemso.bst instead (both on a server environment).

Comment: OK, what's happening is that BibTeX is using the wrong file. You should have 'local' files in the correct places, so `~/texmf/tex/latex/achemso/achemso.cls` and `~/texmf/bibtex/bst/achemso/achemso.bst` (version numbers in folders not recommended: may mess up `kpsewhich` searching).

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot for your prompt help!!

Answer (score 4):

To summarise the comments, this problem is caused by having a mismatching version of `achemso.bst` compared with `achemso.cls`. Normally this comes about as part of a manual or part-manual installation of `achemso`. A check is to run `kpsewhich achemso.bst` and `kpsewhich achemso.cls` from the Command Line/Terminal. A 'correct' installation will have 'similar' paths, for example

```
<install location>/texmf/tex/latex/achemso/achemso.cls
<install location>/texmf/bibtex/bst/achemso/achemso.bst
```

Comment: Note to self: should print version number in `achemso.bst`!